# How to post comments to facebook using open graph

Tags: facebook

I am able to retrieve my fb comment using https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=id, but i am not able to post comment back to fb, below is my code, please give me some guide

```
$accessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
       'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
       'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
));

$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/appid/comments', 'POST',
       array(
    'access_token' => $accessToken,
    'message' => $comemnts
    )
);

echo 'success...';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

`$facebook->api('/appid/comments', 'POST',`

it should be like this

```
api('xxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'POST
```

Where the

- 1st of the 3 xxx parts is the id of facebook page,
- 2nd is the id of the post
- 3ed is the id of the comment you are trying to comment.

Comment: sorry, i am not quite understand, can explain it further more?

Comment: when you fetch results about post you get something like this:
"id": "412331762191099_478565152234426"
that one describes the page and post, now the only thing you need to do is find the id of the comment that you want to comment and attach it to the id above. For example if the id of the comment you want to comment is xxxxxxxxxxxx you will do this 412331762191099_478565152234426_xxxxxxxxxxxx and then put it all in the form described above